# Firebase re-login/additional login removes all user data

Tags: android, json, firebase

Using Firebase Android docs to save a list of data with:

```
String new_status;
new_status = status_update_text.getText().toString();
Firebase postRef = userRef.child("posts");
Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
post1.put("status", new_status);
postRef.push().setValue(post1);
```

Users saved to database after authentication with:

```
//save user to database
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("provider", authData.getProvider());
if(authData.getProviderData().containsKey("displayName")) {
    map.put("displayName", authData.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
   }
   ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(map);
```

Security rules currently:

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
      "$posts": {
      // create new post if it doesn't exist but can't modify or delete posts
      ".write": "!data.exists() || newData.exists()"
      }
}
```

The issue is when the user logs in again all the saved data is erased (I assume) by .setValue(map). I attempted to put the write rule as high as possible as I've read the rules cascade down but I don't understand why it's currently being ignored???

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong:

```
!data.exists() || newData.exists()
```

Say that you write data to a location that already contains data. This evaluates to:

```
!true || true => true
```

You're probably looking for:

```
!data.exists()
```

Also see the [documentation on securing new data vs existing data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-data-variables).

Comment: thanks for your input @frankvanpuffelen. Tried as you suggested but now it doesn't allow any writes? The attempt I initially listed above was taken from the documentation link you provided. See the last heading titled 'Anonymous Chat Example'. According to the comments line 34 is supposed to allow new message creation but no modification or deletion?

Comment: `!data.exists() && newData.exists()"` That snippet from the documentation example uses `&&`, you're using an `||`

Comment: I apologize for that @frankvanpuffelen. However `".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"` prevented any writes too when tested? Went back & tested all 3 ( &&, || and !data.exists() ) versions just to be certain; && and !data.exists() prevent writes while || deletes everything when user logs in again.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the problem correctly, the issue isn't so much with your rules but more so that every time a user authenticates their previously saved information is being erased.  If that is the case then I would say your issue is, as your guessed,

```
ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(map);
```

The setValue() function is going to your specific users node and clearing all of the other data - only replacing it with the displayName.

I think you would want the updateChildren() method opposed to setValue()

```
ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).updateChildren(map);
```

That should only update the username and leave the remaining data in place.

Comment: Thanks @kyle for the input. Wasn't aware from the docs that I could use that method for initial logins but it seems to work. I delete the entire users node but updateChildren re-writes it to the database when called.